# Beyond Compare Search Results

Tags: beyondcompare

it's probably a silly simple question, but here is goes  - how do I export the Comparison Results window content to a file?  (BC version 3.1)

Answer (score 2):

This is better suited to [Scooter Software's forums](http://www.scootersoftware.com/vbulletin/) or [SuperUser.com](https://superuser.com/), but to answer your question:

The "Comparison Results" dialog doesn't have reporting options.  Use the **Session->Folder Compare Report...** menu item to create a hardcopy (plain text or HTML).

Comment: thanks, I needed to compare several comparisons, so a static report wouldn't be enough. I wound up using the XML report, parsing it and uploading the data in the final form to a SQL server. Not too painful.